# Loading previous saved answers Tkinter OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter, loading, optionmenu

I need a help to solve this issue when loading data to tkinter option menu. I have read some answers over Stackoverflow and I believe I am very close, but I can't see where I am mistaking.

The app is a questionnaire with several pages (I added just 2 just to make easier to understand what the app is about) that saves the information on an excel file and now I am trying to load that information back if the user decides to save momentarily and continue later.

> Edited part below:

So far, all my loaded information is being stored but the option menu is not refreshing with the data.

A full running code with the simple part of what I have developed is below:

```
import tkinter as tk, pandas as pd
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

window = tk.Tk()

choices_y_n = ['-', 'Yes', 'No'] 
Questionlist = ["A. Is true?:", "B. Is True? :","C. Is True? :", "D. True? :"]
dash_entry_quality = [" - ", " - ", " - ", " - ", " - ", " - ", " - "]

def global_save(): 
    list_answers = list(map(lambda x: x.get(), var))
    a = ({"Q1": list_answers})    
    dfa = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index').transpose()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("save_data.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    dfa.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Save Files')
    writer.save()
    messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "Progress successfully saved!")  

def load():
    global dash_entry
    file = pd.read_excel("save_data.xlsx")        
    dash_entry = file["Q1"]
    for r in range(len(Questionlist)): 
        var[r].set('')
        option_menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for c in dash_entry:
            option_menu['menu'].add_command(label = c, command = tk._setit(var[r], c))
    messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "information successfully loaded!")  

window.columnconfigure(0, minsize=100)
window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=150)
window.columnconfigure(2, minsize=50)     
tk.Frame.configure(window, background = "white")
ttk.Label(window, text="Group A Checklist", background = "white").grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, pady = 10)
ttk.Label(window, text="Questions: ", background="white").grid(row=2, column=0,columnspan=2, padx=10, pady = 10, sticky="W")
global var, option_menu
var= [tk.StringVar(window) for i in range(len(Questionlist))]
for r in range(len(Questionlist)): 
    ttk.Label(window, text=Questionlist[r], background = "white").grid(row= r+3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady = 10, sticky="W")
    option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(window, var[r], *choices_y_n)
    option_menu.grid(row = r+3, column=2, padx=10, sticky="WE")
ttk.Button(window, text="Save values", command = global_save, width=18).grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, sticky="W")
ttk.Button(window, text="Load values", command = load, width=18).grid(row=17, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, sticky="W")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted waaaay too much code. Please reduce it down to a [mcve]. It sounds like  you're asking how to read an excel file to populate some optionmenus. That shouldn't take but a couple dozen lines to emulate.

Comment: Sorry @BryanOakley, I have edited the code for a simpler version of it. The idea is yes to read an excel file but only if the 'Load" button is clicked.

Comment: Both your buttons have `command = global_save`. You never call `load()`.

Comment: Sorry @fhdrsdg, it was a mistake when I edited to make the file smaller. Just edited it again.

Comment: Why do you try to rebuild the complete OptionMenu? The options stay the same and you just want to set the selected value right? you can simply set the values like `for r in range(len(Questionlist)): var[r].set(dash_entry[r])`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @fhdrsdg! Now it is working! I imagined it was something simple that I wasn't seeing! Can you post the answer as an Answer so for me to accept the solution and close the question?

Comment: Good to hear! I'll write it up as a proper answer to show that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over complicating things. There's no need to rebuild the complete OptionMenu, you can simply update the variables that contain the current answer to the loaded answers:

```
def load():
    file = pd.read_excel("save_data.xlsx")        
    dash_entry = file["Q1"]
    for r in range(len(Questionlist)): 
        var[r].set(dash_entry[r])
    messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "Information successfully loaded!")
```